# How to build a simple Safari 10.1 app extension to inject JavaScript code on Safari Start-up?

Tags: javascript, safari, safari-extension

How I can inject JavaScript code on Safari Start-up

I Need a Safari app extension to inject JavaScript code on Safari Start-up. This JavaScript have to modify page style like in the example bellow:

```
window.querySelectorAll("small.text-gray-light").
            forEach((o) => o.style.display = "none");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set an event listener to inject your JavaScript code every time the DOM content is loaded

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", handle_DOM_when_loaded);
function handle_DOM_when_loaded(event) {
    // your code
};
```